# How to detect native screen resolution or scaling factor of the secondary monitor at Windows 10

Tags: c++, windows, multiple-monitors, highdpi

Have two monitors: secondary to the left from primary. Resolutions:

```
Primary:   2560*1440 scaling 100%
Secondary: 1920*1200 scaling 150%
```

At the program start it does `EnumDisplayMonitors` which gives following RECTs:

```
Primary:   0,0,2560,1440
Secondary: -1920,0,-640,800
```

Also I tried the code:

```
int width, height;
RECT rect = { -1920, 0, -640, 800 };
SystemParametersInfoA(SPI_SETWORKAREA, 0, &rect, 0);
width = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN);
height = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN);
```

but `width` and `height` always have dimensions of the primary monitor.

How to detect native resolution of the secondary monitor `1920*1200` or the scaling factor `150%`?

This doesn't work either, gives `1280*800`:

```
BOOL CALLBACK EnumMonitorCallback(HMONITOR hMon, HDC hdc, LPRECT rect, LPARAM param)
{
    MONITORINFOEXA mi;
    mi.cbSize = sizeof(mi);
    GetMonitorInfoA(hMon, &mi);
    HDC dc = CreateDCA("DISPLAY", mi.szDevice, NULL, NULL);
    int width = GetDeviceCaps(dc, HORZRES);
    int height = GetDeviceCaps(dc, VERTRES);
    DeleteDC(dc);
    return TRUE;
}
```

Comment: The second monitor has an actual rectangle of 1280 x 800 at 100%. When scaled up to 150%, it is 1920 x 1200.

Comment: The secondary monitor has original resolution `1920*1200`. In the monitor settings I set 150% scaling. And now any request for real resolution for secondary monitor returns `1280*800`. And I need either to detect `1920*1200` or scaling `150%`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your application should [indicate High DPI awareness](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/hidpi/high-dpi-desktop-application-development-on-windows) so that OS does not try to lie about resolutions trying to mimic legacy environment. Then [DXGI output enumeration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/dxgi/nf-dxgi-idxgiadapter-enumoutputs) [gets you](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/dxgi/ns-dxgi-dxgi_output_desc) the requested data.

You can quick-check this using tool at the bottom of [this blog post](http://alax.info/blog/1881). I have two monitors at 3840x2160, the first with 175% scaling and the second with 150%. Note "desktop coordinates" and "monitor DPI" in the printout below:

```
#### Output: \\.\DISPLAY4

 * Desktop Coordinates: (0, 0) - (3840, 2160); 3840 x 2160
 * Attached To Desktop: 1
 * Rotation: DXGI_MODE_ROTATION_IDENTITY
 * Monitor: 0x000100B3
 * Physical Monitors: LG ULTRA HD(DisplayPort) (0x00000000)
 * Bits Per Color: 10
 * Color Space: DXGI_COLOR_SPACE_RGB_FULL_G22_NONE_P709
 * Primaries, White Point: R { 0.652, 0.335 }, G { 0.305, 0.637 }, B { 0.148, 0.062 }; { 0.313, 0.329 }
 * Luminance: Min 0.500, Max 270.000, Max Full Frame 270.000
 * Hardware Composition Support: DXGI_HARDWARE_COMPOSITION_SUPPORT_FLAG_FULLSCREEN | DXGI_HARDWARE_COMPOSITION_SUPPORT_FLAG_CURSOR_STRETCHED
 * Monitor DPI, MDT_EFFECTIVE_DPI: 168, 168 ; System DPI 168
 * Monitor DPI, MDT_ANGULAR_DPI: 161, 160
 * Monitor DPI, MDT_RAW_DPI: 162, 161

…

#### Output: \\.\DISPLAY5

 * Desktop Coordinates: (3840, 0) - (7680, 2160); 3840 x 2160
 * Attached To Desktop: 1
 * Rotation: DXGI_MODE_ROTATION_IDENTITY
 * Monitor: 0x000200B1
 * Physical Monitors: LG ULTRA HD(DisplayPort) (0x00000000)
 * Bits Per Color: 10
 * Color Space: DXGI_COLOR_SPACE_RGB_FULL_G22_NONE_P709
 * Primaries, White Point: R { 0.652, 0.335 }, G { 0.305, 0.637 }, B { 0.148, 0.062 }; { 0.313, 0.329 }
 * Luminance: Min 0.500, Max 270.000, Max Full Frame 270.000
 * Hardware Composition Support: DXGI_HARDWARE_COMPOSITION_SUPPORT_FLAG_FULLSCREEN | DXGI_HARDWARE_COMPOSITION_SUPPORT_FLAG_CURSOR_STRETCHED
 * Monitor DPI, MDT_EFFECTIVE_DPI: 144, 144 ; System DPI 168
 * Monitor DPI, MDT_ANGULAR_DPI: 161, 160
 * Monitor DPI, MDT_RAW_DPI: 162, 161
```

Answer (score 3):

[`GetSystemMetrics`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getsystemmetrics) calls for `SM_CXSCREEN` or `SM_CYSCREEN` will return the resolution of the primary display.  To get the resolution for secondary monitors, you need to use [`GetDeviceCaps`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-getdevicecaps) or the [Multiple Display Monitors API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/gdi/multiple-display-monitors-reference).

Comment: I took that here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/gdi/multiple-monitor-system-metrics

Comment: "*The `GetSystemMetrics` function returns values **for the primary monitor**,...*"

Comment: This solution doesn't work either. It returns again `1280*800` instead of `1920*1200`

Answer (score 1):

Use [GetScaleFactorForMonitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellscalingapi/nf-shellscalingapi-getscalefactorformonitor) function to obtain the scale factor.

Comment: Please read about [answer]. While the contents of this link might actually solve the problem, link-only answers are discouraged on this site. Links tend to break and then the answer loses its value. It is better to include the essential parts of the link as text in the answer itself and provide the link as a reference. Your plain-text answer looks like: `Use GetScaleFactorForMonitor function to obtain the scale factor.` which doesn't provide much information. If you think the link alone can help, post it as a comment (if you have 50 rep) instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```cpp
void GetMonitorRealResolution(HMONITOR monitor, int* pixelsWidth, int* pixelsHeight)
{
    MONITORINFOEX info = { sizeof(MONITORINFOEX) };
    winrt::check_bool(GetMonitorInfo(monitor, &info));
    DEVMODE devmode = {};
    devmode.dmSize = sizeof(DEVMODE);
    winrt::check_bool(EnumDisplaySettings(info.szDevice, ENUM_CURRENT_SETTINGS, &devmode));
    *pixelsWidth = devmode.dmPelsWidth;
    *pixelsHeight = devmode.dmPelsHeight;
}
```

It will return that native resolution in any case, even if the DPI awareness of the process will cause the OS to lie.